# Tripadvisor fit to main div

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to put my tripadvisor into a bigger div..(width, height)..and with width it's not a problem, but I can't strech to fit with the height too.. What can I do?

```html
<div style="width:1000px; height:500px;">
  <div id="TA_selfserveprop883" class="TA_selfserveprop">
    <ul id="WFAboR" class="TA_links DuIxc6Zcnwl">
      <li id="7njRA4" class="iXvW5GLL">
        <a href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: 
Here is how it looks, I want to cover the part where is the arrow..to fit complete

Here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtDTv.png).

**P.S:** The width and height of the main are dynamic.

Comment: So you want to disregard the proportions of the image to make it fit its parent?

Comment: @BenM yes. I want the widget to fit its parent

Comment: Widget? Do you mean image? And you wish to stretch to fit, regardless of proportions?

Comment: @BenM look for my update